# How can Wolverine survive a Nuclear Bomb?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

In Wolverine (2013), he was exposed to a nuclear explosion with an epicenter in his field of view. At such temperature any organic or inorganic material would only exist in Atomic form, how can wolverine withstand such high temperature? In support of my argument, this is an excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions)

> *The physical-damage mechanisms of a nuclear weapon (blast and thermal radiation) are identical to those of conventional explosives, but the energy produced by a nuclear explosive is millions of times more powerful per gram and the temperatures reached are briefly in the tens of millions of degrees.*

N2 (Nitrogen Gas) is the most stable gas present in our atmosphere since it has a trivalent bond, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen#Properties)

> Unstable allotropes of nitrogen consisting of more than two nitrogen atoms, such as N3 and N4, have been produced in the laboratory. Under extremely high pressures (1.1 million atm) and high temperatures (2000 K)

This implies that even the most stable gas in our atmosphere is volatile and exists in atomic form at such extreme temperatures. How can possibly Wolverine survive this?

Comment: I believe he already has but this *feels* off-topic. You might have better luck over on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Comment: I'm not sure about any official "canon" answer, but the impression I got while watching the movie was that he was regenerating flesh as it got burned off.  This, of course, begs the question "how fast can Wolverine regenerate?"  As far as the movie is concerned, I suspect the answer is "as fast as required to make it look cool."

Comment: This answer from [Sci-Fi SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/could-wolverine-survive-a-nuclear-bomb) will help. Before people start posting **similar** stuff here.

Comment: @Steve-O I beg to differ on this, temperatures at the nuclear bomb site are bound to be as high as surface of the Sun, there are no cells to regenerate because every thing is Atom, that too independent from any interaction from any other atom at that temperature. So how is regeneration even possible?

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena: _How is regeneration possible ?_ You are questioning the very **X** quality of **X-Men**.

Comment: @Rahul So we basically assume that he survives!

Comment: @Rahul No I'm not, all I'm saying is X-men are caused due to mutations in DNA, but at that temperature there is no DNA.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena: Take a look at answer on Sci-Fi SE.

Comment: @Rahul So 'NO' is a popular opinion! But according to the comic he survives, without a reasonable explanation! Please point out anything I'm missing here! \m/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48896/discussion-between-rahul-and-saurabh-saxena).

Comment: "Can Wolverine survive a nuclear bomb?" Well, he did, so... yes.

Comment: In the _movies_, who knows. In the _comics_, there's no question.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena there are mutants with powers that work at subatomic or quantum levels. Omega level mutants. And mutants who's powers defy physics. Or have powers over the fundamentals forces of physics. Or magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few key points:

1. Wolverine was not in the epicenter.
2. The epicenter of the Hiroshima bomb was 500 meters in the air. It's fireball did not touch the ground. Minimal fall out, intended to cause soft body damage without too much structural damage.
3. The farther from the hypocenter, the less damage.
4. The Hiroshima bomb was 18 kilotons of atomic power. **Weak** compared to modern day weapons, and the most damage was under 2 kilo meters.
5. Only a fourth of Hiroshima's population died immediately. Another fourth died from injuries and radiation. Half the city survived.
6. Buildings and people near the hypocenter survived, Wolverine further away would too. Plus he was underground.

[image]

From the movie, we can see where Wolverine was in relation to the city.

He's across a river, the sea to his back, mountains in the distance.

[image]

### Frankly, the movie made it easier.

The movie shows a ground burst. A ground burst causes more damage to buildings, more fallout, but the explosive force is **WEAKER** because the shockwave doesn't build up. Then again, the fireball in the real explosion never touched the ground.

Answer (score -2):

Yes he can.  And he did.

While it may seem a bit of a cop-out, you have to remember that Wolverine's skeleton is comprised of Adamantium.

Why is this central and important?  Because Adamantium doesn't really exist.  Adamantium takes on the properties of whatever the authors (Lee and Kirby) need it to take on.  If it means that Wolverine's regenerative power allows him to survive a nuclear blast, then it allows Wolverine to survive a nuclear blast.

You can't assign "real world" properties and probabilities to a fictional element, it's not going to work.  Just as you can't ask how someone can shoot a laserbeam out of their eyes and not damage their retina or eyelids.  The character does what the character needs to do, and science need not be involved.

Comment: Logan's healing factor is not due to his Adamantium; if anything his metal skeleton _depresses_ his healing factor because it's poisoning him.

Comment: I think you missed the point.  We're dealing with a fictional universe, where rules of nature need not apply.

Comment: If the adamantine is more or less protecting his organic bones from being vaporized, then theoretically, he could regenerate from the bones up.

Comment: ... He didn't have his Adamantium in Hiroshima... A few decades too early.